# multipart/form-data and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm having this jsp page.

```
<form method="post" action="addBook.do?reqCode=submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
</form>
```

When I submit, I got this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.<clinit>(DiskFileItem.java:103)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.DefaultFileItemFactory.createItem(DefaultFileItemFactory.java:103)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:358)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:310)
at org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.java:193)
```

I'm using struts-1.2.9.jar , common-io-1.3.2.jar and common-file-upload-1.2.1.jar

I didn't even write code for the controller. Just with the jsp, I got that error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is here : http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#fileforms

Comment: Yes, I had to use custom servlet. Struts's ActionServlet was the one gave me the problem.Thanks!