# Problem uploading a file with ajax in appengine

Tags: java, ajax, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I need to send the content of a file to a Spring webService with Ajax in a Google AppEngine Application. So I've used [jquery ajaxFileUpload plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/).

```
<form id="load_form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
    <input name="file" type="file" id="upload_files" value="Browse"/>
    <input type="button"" id="upload_file" value="Load file"/>
</form>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
$("#upload_file").click(function(){

        $.ajaxFileUpload
        (
            {
                url: '/myproject/uploadFile.json',
                secureuri: false,
                fileElementId: 'upload_files',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, status) {
                    alert("OK");
                },
                error: function (data, status, e) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            }
        );

        return false;
    });
```

and in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile.json", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> readFile(
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required=false) MultipartFile file,
        Model model) throws Exception{
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm not receiving in the file parameter the file content (it's always null) and with firebug I can see that I'm sending the content of the file in a parameter called "file". But I'm not receiving them though this method is invoked (I have a breakpoint in it and it stops in it). If I remove required=false from file param a 400 error is given, so it looks as it cannot find the file param.

I'm using Spring 3.0.4.

Any idea of what may be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are result oriented in this case, you can use [custom servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872081/multipart-form-data-and-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-rmi-server-uid-is-a).